# How to check total disk usage in VMware ESXi through powershell?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli, esxi

I want to calculate the total disk capacity of an ESXi host (not the VMs). I want to check the total disk capacity, free and used space of ESXi host via PowerShell.

I am calculating CPU and RAM usage by using the below command:

```
(Get-VMHost $server | Get-Stat -Stat "mem.usage.average" -IntervalMins 10 | Measure-Object Value -Average).Average
```

Please suggest a way to calculate disk usage. I know about disk.usage.average parameter but I don't want this, I want space calculation in GB/MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Get-Datastore` [cmdlet](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-65/index.jsp#com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/Get-Datastore.html).

```
PS /Users/philip> Get-Datastore

Name                               FreeSpaceGB      CapacityGB
----                               -----------      ----------
Synology                               632.840       7,317.147
SSD01                                  111.347         476.750


PS /Users/philip> Get-Datastore -Name synology

Name                               FreeSpaceGB      CapacityGB
----                               -----------      ----------
Synology                               632.840       7,317.147
```

This is only for getting information about the datastores on which VM's are located, not the actual installation of esxi itself.